# Shiny app with theme can't change button background color

Tags: r, shiny, shinythemes

I'm trying to change the background color of a button in a Shiny app, but for some reason I can't make the color change. When I look at the html, I can't even find an id for the button, I only see an id for the text inside the button.

I think this is due to `shinythemes`, but I'm unsure. How do I change the button color in this sample app? Can anyone verify they have the same issue if they run this app, or maybe it is just my setup.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui = fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"), 
    navbarPage("App Name", selected = "Tab1", 
        id = "navbar",
        position = "fixed-top", 
        tabPanel("Tab1", id = "tab1Id",
            #padding between navbar and page when using fixed-top
            tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"), 
            fluidPage(
                actionButton("saveBtn2", "Update Schedule", 
                    icon("floppy-o"), 
                    #style="color: #0000ff;border-color: #2e6da4; background-color: #0000ff"
                    style = "background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to try `actionBttn`.

```
ui = fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"), 
  navbarPage("App Name", selected = "Tab1", 
             id = "navbar",
             position = "fixed-top", 
             tabPanel("Tab1", id = "tab1Id",
                      #padding between navbar and page when using fixed-top
                      tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"), 
                      fluidPage(
                        actionBttn('insertBtn1', 
                                   'Add variable',
                                   style = "simple",
                                   color = "primary",
                                   icon=icon("floppy-o"),
                                   size = "sm",
                                   block = FALSE,
                                   no_outline = TRUE  
                        ),
                        actionButton("saveBtn2", "Update Schedule", 
                                     icon("floppy-o"), 
                                     #style="color: #0000ff;border-color: #2e6da4; background-color: #0000ff"
                                     style = "background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black"
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

[image: output]